# How to link activities to menu and acces them

Tags: java, android, android-activity

> i have created a project with a menu (not empty project) that should open an list of my activities (and it does that) but when i want to open one of the activities that is already shown it doest work. It doesnt open the specified activity but instead it opens  the main activity and so on, how can i link them up ? . Thanks.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_calendar) {
        Intent i=new Intent(this, Calendar.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    if (id == R.id.nav_info) {
        Intent i=new Intent(this, CarInfo.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    if (id == R.id.nav_expenses) {
        Intent i=new Intent(this, Expenses.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    if (id == R.id.nav_map) {
        Intent i=new Intent(this, Map.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    if (id == R.id.nav_service) {
        Intent i=new Intent(this, Service.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

> That's how i link every of my activity  to menu.
>    I tried this too still doesnt do what i like: 
>   I tried to link them like that :

```
public void CarInfo(View view){
Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, CarInfo.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

}

the problem i think it might be in the manifest:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Calendar"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".CarInfo"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Expenses"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".History"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Map"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Service"></activity>
</application>
```

If i link only 1 activity its works, but how can I link them all ?

Comment: The intended `Activity` should start just fine. Also, this code seems correct. Please share any other relevant piece of code from your app and/or error/debug logs.

Comment: I think the problem might be here, in the manifest :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return true in the `onOptionsItemSelected()` when you use the event and leave the `super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);` when it's not handled.

Answer (score 1):

**Create Menu Item in XML**

`<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/bookmark_menu" 
          android:title="@string/bookmark"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>`

**Override onCreateOptionsMenu and use getMenuInflater().inflate**

`public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }`

**Override onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) to Handle Click Event**

`public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.bookmark_menu:
                Toast.makeText(this, "You have selected Bookmark Menu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me... hope it will work for u

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Wishlist.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.action_settings1) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AboutUs.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.action_settings2) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Contact_Us.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.action_cart) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Cart.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.action_search) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivitySearch.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

need to use **else-if**